# Switch function based on input file type in shiny apps

Tags: shiny, shiny-server, shiny-reactivity, seurat

How to switch function based on input type which is based on user input.

Here I have two files types broadly one is

```
".mtx", ".tsv",".gz",
```

and the other is

```
".h5ad"
```

So here the operation is performed as such when the user opts for the first set of file types one Function is already called named as `rnaApp::ReadDoi`

Now I have created a new function for .h5ad files to read and generate a file type, so when user choose .h5ad file I would like the new function to be invoked instead of the default function , which is `rnaApp::ReadH5AD`

The part of the code that does is the reading of the input file type is this.

```
observeEvent(input$btnUploadNext,{
        # Data can be either in input[[File]] (if uploaded) or tmpData[[File]] (source ICA)
        # This if condidtion will check both and only if all 3
        # files are present (can be from any source) then logic is executed
        withProgress(
          message = "Processing uploaded data",
          value = 0,{
            incProgress(0.1, detail = "Reading files...")
            
            ## Preparing a data directory
            tmpDataDir <- "tmpScRnaData"
            
            # remove tmp folder to avoid affects from previous uploads
            unlink(tmpDataDir, recursive=TRUE)
            
            # prepare/download files
            prepareFile(fileType="Upload", input, tmpData, outDir=tmpDataDir)
            
            
            
            tryCatch({
              #detect organism
              detectOrganism(tmpDataDir,data)
              
              ## Shifting to ReadDoi, all files now downloaded in a tmpDir and then sent for creating Seurat Object
              expression_matrix <- rnaApp::ReadDoi("tmpScRnaData")
              
              
              incProgress(0.5, detail = "Creating seurat object...")
              seuratObject <- suppressWarnings(CreateSeuratObject(counts = expression_matrix))   
              incProgress(0.9, detail = "Creating QC metrics...")             
              seuratObject[["percent.mt"]] <- suppressWarnings(PercentageFeatureSet(seuratObject, pattern = "^MT-|^mt-"))
              
              ## percent.mt from  data contains numeric values along with NaNs
              ## NaN causes issues in finding min, max or range. So replacing it with 0
              seuratObject@meta.data$percent.mt[is.nan(seuratObject@meta.data$percent.mt)] = 0
              
              showNotification(paste0("Created Seurat object's size:",
                                      seuratObject%>%object.size%>%format(.,unit="Mb"),
                                      " (", nrow(seuratObject),"genes,",ncol(seuratObject),"cells)"))    
              
              
              setProgress(1)
              
              # update main tab 
              data$seuratObject = seuratObject
              updateTabItems(session=parentSession, inputId= "mainTabs", "CellSelection")
              unlink(tmpDataDir, recursive=TRUE)
            }, 
            interrupt = function(x){rnaApp::getFileErrorModal()},
            error = function(x){rnaApp::getFileErrorModal()}
            # Disabled warning since ReadDoi raises a warning if barcodeSummary file not provided
            # warning = function(x){rnaApp::getFileErrorModal()}
            )
          }
        )
        # }                
      })
```

Now my objective is How do I switch from `rnaApp::ReadDoi` to `rnaApp::ReadH5AD` based on user input type, which so far Im not sure how to put

as this is the part where the files and made into one file which goes downstream to make seuratobject so How do i make a switch case with `rnaApp::ReadH5AD` here when the input is `.h5ad` file in case of `rnaApp::ReadDoi`

```
expression_matrix <- rnaApp::ReadDoi("tmpScRnaData")
```

Any suggestion or help would be really apprecaited.

**UPDATED CODE**

```
observeEvent(input$btnUploadNext, {
  # Data can be either in input[[File]] (if uploaded) or tmpData[[File]] (source ICA)
  # This if condition will check both and only if all 3
  # files are present (can be from any source) then logic is executed
  withProgress(
    message = "Processing uploaded data",
    value = 0, {
      incProgress(0.1, detail = "Reading files...")

      ## Preparing a data directory
      tmpDataDir <- "tmpScRnaData"

      # remove tmp folder to avoid affects from previous uploads
      unlink(tmpDataDir, recursive = TRUE)

      # prepare/download files
      prepareFile(fileType = "Upload", input, tmpData, outDir = tmpDataDir)

      tryCatch({
        # detect organism
        detectOrganism(tmpDataDir, data)

        ## Determine the appropriate read function based on file type
        fileExtension <- tools::file_ext(tmpData$datapath)
        if (fileExtension == "h5ad") {
          read_function <- rnaApp::ReadH5AD
        } else {
          read_function <- rnaApp::ReadDoi
        }

        ## Read the data using the determined read function
        expression_matrix <- read_function(tmpDataDir)

        incProgress(0.5, detail = "Creating Seurat object...")
        seuratObject <- suppressWarnings(CreateSeuratObject(counts = expression_matrix))
        incProgress(0.9, detail = "Creating QC metrics...")
        seuratObject[["percent.mt"]] <- suppressWarnings(PercentageFeatureSet(seuratObject, pattern = "^MT-|^mt-"))

        ## percent.mt from  data contains numeric values along with NaNs
        ## NaN causes issues in finding min, max, or range. So replacing it with 0
        seuratObject@meta.data$percent.mt[is.nan(seuratObject@meta.data$percent.mt)] <- 0

        showNotification(
          paste0(
            "Created Seurat object's size:",
            seuratObject %>% object.size %>% format(., unit = "Mb"),
            " (", nrow(seuratObject), "genes,", ncol(seuratObject), "cells)"
          )
        )

        setProgress(1)

        # update main tab
        data$seuratObject <- seuratObject
        updateTabItems(session = parentSession, inputId = "mainTabs", "CellSelection")
        unlink(tmpDataDir, recursive = TRUE)
      },
      interrupt = function(x) { rnaApp::getFileErrorModal() },
      error = function(x) { rnaApp::getFileErrorModal() }
      # Disabled warning since ReadDoi raises a warning if barcodeSummary file not provided
      # warning = function(x){rnaApp::getFileErrorModal()}
      )
    }
  )
  # }
})
```

Comment: What prevents you from using `read_function <- if(however you detect .h5ad files) rnaApp::ReadH5AD else rnaApp::ReadDoi` and then `expression_matrix <- read_function("tmpScRnaData")`?

Comment: I did think about it but i was not sure how to translate that into R syntactically  `read_function <- if(however you detect .h5ad files) rnaApp::ReadH5AD else rnaApp::ReadDoi and then expression_matrix <- read_function("tmpScRnaData")` so this should be going after ` detectOrganism(tmpDataDir,data)` line isn;t it?

Comment: I don't fully understand your code, but putting it there seems reasonable.

Comment: dumb question  `read_function <- if(however you detect .h5ad files) rnaApp::ReadH5AD else rnaApp::ReadDoi and then expression_matrix <- read_function("tmpScRnaData")` can you make it like what should I put inside the main function i posted since even i just have to add that New function to the existing code  which it self is huge code base but i figured out that part is where the file reading is occurring

Comment: @pajonk i updated the code if you could have a look and let me know if I'm doing correctly or not I would be really glad.

Comment: Looks ok to me.

Comment: @pajonk this is the error `cannot open file 'tmpScRnaData/NA'` when the modified code is ran as this is not able to get the path